# Programmatically Updating a document library in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling, events

Im quite new to SHarepoint. I have a requirement like, i need to move some documents from different document libraries to a document library named "Region". So that each time a document is updated in these document libraries , the document should be updated in the library "Region" as well.
I wrote a c# function in a class library,to copy the documents to the library and added the dll to that sites Bin folder.Function is working fine. But Im stuck up , Im n ot sure where to call this function.In which event should i write it, so that each time any of these documents are modified, that change has to be reflected in the "Region" library .

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a SharePoint event handler and attach it to all the document libraries where you change the documents. You will then override the `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated` methods to perform the copying.

See more info in this StackOverflow discussion: [SharePoint running a method when item added to a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819798/sharepoint-running-a-method-when-item-added-to-a-library)

Answer (score 1):

Using an event handler is probably the best way to go as mentioned by naivists. Alternatively, if the work you are carrying out is part of a larger whole, e.g. a Workflow, then you may want to consider creating a Visual Studio Workflow, which may be quite complex to get started with, or use a simple tool like the Workflow Power Pack that allows simple C# snippets to be added directly to SharePoint Designer Workflows.

Have a look at [these articles](http://muhimbi.com/blog/labels/WPP.html). More info [can be found here](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/Summary.aspx).

Note that I worked on the Power Pack so I am biased. Having said that it works great ;-)